# Is there a way to get the song ID (for use in the Genius API) from the song's webpage?

Tags: web-scraping, genius-api

I am building an app where I want users to be able to supply a Genius song url, and then get some of the data from the song page for use in the app. I am not sure how to convert the url into a song ID that I can use in the Genius API

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the author already post an almost identical question few minutes before